# paypal and php and phpbb and 303 error

Tags: php, paypal, content-management-system, phpbb3, http-status-code-303

I have been trying to get a system set up on my web site.  I am using the CMS freeware called PHPBB and I am using a modification written by one of the people who is a fan of this system.

The mod is supposed to make it such that members pay for a subscription using paypal.  I have installed and set up the system without doing any special modifications that I intend to do later.  I have set it up using my paypal account to receive the payment.  But when I ran a test using a test membership, I get a strange error.  I have posted information about this error o nthe phpbb web forum here: https://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=70&t=2126610&start=1155#p13632936

The error is basically "failed with code: 303 - rifle".  When I googled this 303 error I found that this is typically a hardware error and so I first opened a chat with my internet service provider.  They opened a ticket and said they would get back with me.

Here is a small screen shot of the error: http://www.arguemax.com/images/problems/5-21-2014/Capture_02.PNG

And here is a recorded test session that produces the error: http://youtu.be/728GYPBLYhU

How would you suggest I go about debugging this?

(UPDATE) OK, I looked at the PHP code that calls paypal.  "303" and "rifle" are results straight from paypal and so this must mean something and that thing must be something I can use to fix this.  What does these two paypal errors mean?  I mean, there is a "results" array of strings that the php code gets back from paypal and 303 is the contents of results[0] and "rifle" is the contents of results[1]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was looking around and I found something.
http://www.arguemax.com/images/problems/5-21-2014/Capture_03.PNG

When I removed, actually, commented out, the line, it seems everything works fine.  Or at least now it runs to completion.  I still have some minor adjustments to make, like making it USD.
Watch this new video I made:
http://youtu.be/LEcYSk48-eA